# Add a new column to a dataframe with multiple condition based on list and a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops

I have two differents object

a list :

```
list_color <- c("#f87970", "#c59b04", "#5ab70b", "#04c195", "#06b7eb")
```

a dataframe :

```
head(data)
  Cal    Cre
1 ca     h1  
2 cb     h2 
3 ca     h3  
4 cd     h4
5 ce     h5
6 cb     h2 
7 ca     h3  
8 cd     h4
```

I try to create a new column with a color corresponding to each value from "ca1" column

```
      Cal    Cre    Color
    1 ca     h1    "#f87970"
    2 cb     h2    "#c59b04"
    3 ca     h3    "#f87970"
    4 cd     h4    "#5ab70b"
    5 ce     h5    "#04c195"
    6 cb     h2    "#c59b04"
    7 ca     h3    "#f87970"
    8 cd     h4    "#5ab70b"
```

I try to create a double loop, but it is not working.
My code :

```
for(k in list_color){
    for(i in data$Ca1){
       data$Color <- ifelse(i , k, "None")
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why `ca` gets `#f87970` and not another color? If not, maybe you can try `list_color[as.integer(as.factor(data$cal))]`.

Comment: Yes there is a reason I would like the same color link to the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach without using loops with dataframes to identify unique values and then assign the color. The approach uses `match()`. Here the code:

```
#Colors
list_color <- c("#f87970", "#c59b04", "#5ab70b", "#04c195", "#06b7eb")
dfcolors <- data.frame(id=1:length(list_color),list_color,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Unique values
uni <- unique(df$Ca1)
dfca1 <- data.frame(id=1:length(uni),uni,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Now match ca1 and colors
dfcolors$ca1 <- dfca1[match(dfcolors$id,dfca1$id),"uni"]
#Match with df
df$Color <- dfcolors[match(df$Ca1,dfcolors$ca1),"list_color"]
```

Output:

```
df
  Ca1 Cre   Color
1  ca  h1 #f87970
2  cb  h2 #c59b04
3  ca  h3 #f87970
4  cd  h4 #5ab70b
5  ce  h5 #04c195
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Ca1 = c("ca", "cb", "ca", "cd", "ce"), Cre = c("h1", 
"h2", "h3", "h4", "h5")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match` on the `unique` values of 'Ca1'

```
df$Color <- list_color[match(df$Ca1, unique(df$Ca1))]
```

-output

```
df
#  Ca1 Cre   Color
#1  ca  h1 #f87970
#2  cb  h2 #c59b04
#3  ca  h3 #f87970
#4  cd  h4 #5ab70b
#5  ce  h5 #04c195
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Ca1 = c("ca", "cb", "ca", "cd", "ce"), Cre = c("h1", 
"h2", "h3", "h4", "h5")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
), class = "data.frame")
```